# iPhone 7+ safari browser bottom fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have a website for customizing mobile case. Its working perfect on all browser except iPhone 7+ safari. The bottom navigation is not showing above the toolbar of safari.
Please help me to resolve this problem

[image]

Comment: please css html especific

Comment: You need to provide your code—a [mcve]. If you provide code that reproduces the behavior, we can help you.